# Is there a way to pass a persistent global variable between renderers in Electron?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I'm trying to set up a persistent variable for my MathsTutor app that allows me to store the number values that are generated in a HTML page even after a user leaves and returns. My full script can be found on my github (https://github.com/proshanto-c/MathsTutor) if it would help to be able to read it. What usually happens is that when a person goes onto one of the subpages, say for addition, they click a generate button and it makes two random numbers, and the numbers drop down from above the screen. Right now, when the user returns to the main menu and then comes back to the page the page is completely reset and there is no way of getting back the numbers they had before. I would like the numbers to stay persistent, and I've been trying to use a preload script that exposes global variables using `contextBridge` which hold the values long-term but that hasn't been working.

My project is split over quite a few render files so I'll try and only keep the relevant parts in this breakdown:

`main.js:`

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, Menu} = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');

let mainWindow;

const createWindow = () => {
    // Create a window
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        show: false,
        autoHideMenuBar: true,
        webPreferences: ({
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'scripts', 'preload.js'),
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
        }),
        minWidth: 700,
        minHeight: 400,
    });
    mainWindow.maximize();
    mainWindow.show();

    // Load HTML into window
    mainWindow.loadFile('index.html');
}
...
```

`scripts/preload.js:`

```
const {contextBridge} = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('integers', {
    m1: 0,
    m2: 0,
    a1: 0,
    a2: 0,
})
```

`scripts/generator.js:`

```
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');

// Initialising document variables

// Randomiser section
const digitSelector = document.getElementById('digitSelector');
const randButton = document.getElementById('randomise');
const digitSlider = document.getElementById('digits');
const sliderValue = document.getElementById('sliderValue');
// Problem section
const problem = document.getElementById('problemBox');
const number1 = document.getElementById('number1');
const number2 = document.getElementById('number2');
const answer = document.getElementById('answer');
const submit = document.getElementById('submit');
const ci = document.getElementById('ci');
// Exit app button
const closeApp = document.getElementById('closeApp');
// Pull the name of the page
const operation = document.title;

let v1;
let v2;
// Total value for checking answers
let total;


// Generate a random number with a set number of digits
const generateRandomInteger = (noOfDigits) => {
...
} 

const makeAnswerable = () => {
    number1.innerText = v1;
    number2.innerText = v2;
    problem.style.visibility = "visible";
    problem.style.opacity = "1";
    problem.style.transform = "translateX(0)";
    digitSelector.style.left = "100%";
    digitSelector.style.transform = "translateX(-100%)";
    ci.innerText = '';
    answer.value = '';
}

// Does five main things:
// Randomise the two numbers in the problem seen on screen
// Reset the answer message and clear the answer box
// Sets the total to the actual expected answer to the problem on screen
// Bring the problem box down from behind the top two banners with the numbers generated
// Move the randomiser section to the right of the screen
const randomiseNumbers = (noOfDigits) => {
    v1 = generateRandomInteger(noOfDigits);
    v2 = generateRandomInteger(noOfDigits);
    makeAnswerable();
    if (operation === "Addition") {
        total = v1+v2;
        window.integers.a1 = v1;
        window.integers.a2 = v2;
    }
    else if (operation === "Multiplication") {
        total = v1*v2;
        window.integers.m1 = v1;
        window.integers.m2 = v2;
    }
}

// Run randomiseNumbers when the generate button is clicked
randButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const digits = digitSlider.value;
    randomiseNumbers(digits);
});

...

if (operation === "Addition" && window.integers.a1 !== 0) {
    v1 = window.integers.a1;
    v2 = window.integers.a2;
    total = v1+v2;
    makeAnswerable();
}
else if (operation === "Multiplication" && window.integers.m1 !== 0) {
    v1 = window.integers.m1;
    v2 = window.integers.m2;
    total = v1*v2;
    makeAnswerable();
}
```

`pages/addition.html:` (`multiplication.html` is the same, `index.html` is just a main menu)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
...
        <title>Addition</title>
    </head>

    <body>
...
        <div class="mainContent">
            <!-- Randomiser box -->
            <div class="digitSelector" id="digitSelector">
                <h3>How many digits would you like the integers to have?</h3>
                <div class="sliderInfo">
                    <input type="range" min="1" max="5" value="3" class="digitSlider" id="digits">
                    <h3 id="sliderValue">3</h3>
                    <button class="randomiser" id="randomise">Generate</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Problem box (starts off screen to the top) -->
            <div class="problemBox" id="problemBox">
                <h2>Try adding these numbers together:</h2>
                <div>
                    <h3 id="number1"></h3>
                    <h3 id="number2"></h3>
                    <input type="number" class="number" min="0" step="1" max="1000000" id="answer" name="answer" placeholder="Answer here">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Check answer">
                    <h3 id="ci"></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script src="../scripts/generator.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are not creating your Electron window(s) with URL's (EG: [win.loadURL()](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winloadurlurl-options)), one cannot use the browsers local storage to store your most recent numbers.

Instead, upon random number generation, you can just pass your random numbers to your main process via IPC. Your `preload.js` script will aid in this process.

When, say in this example, your `addition` window is closed, the numbers will persist in the main process.

When the `addition` window is re-opened (IE: Re-created) it can send the numbers (if defined) back to the `addition` window via IPC to be displayed in the UI.

> Note: This example does not persist when the main window is closed. For persistence to occur, one could save the numbers to a json file everytime they are updated. Then upon application start-up, load the number back into the main process local variables before the main window is created.

In the minimum reproducible example below, for testing purposes I have created a basic `generateNumber()` function in the `addition.html` file.

---

`main.js` (main process)

The `main.js` file is responsible for creating the two windows (`main` and `addition`), updating the persistent numbers when received from the `addition` window and sending them back to the `addition` window when it is re-created.

```js
// Import required electron modules
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

// Import required Node modules
const nodePath = require('path');

// Prevent garbage collection
let number1;
let number2;

let mainWindow;
let additionWindow;

function createMainWindow() {
    const mainWindow = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            sandbox: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    mainWindow.loadFile(nodePath.join(__dirname, 'main-window.html'))
        .then(() => { mainWindow.show(); });

    return mainWindow;
}

function createAdditionWindow() {
    const additionWindow = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 150,
        y: 150,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        parent: mainWindow, // Make it a child of the main window
        modal: true,        // Make it a child of the main window
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            sandbox: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    additionWindow.loadFile(nodePath.join(__dirname, 'addition-window.html'))
        .then(() => {
            if (number1 !== undefined && number2 !== undefined) {
                additionWindow.webContents.send('previous-numbers', {'number1': number1, 'number2': number2});
            }
        })
        .then(() => { additionWindow.show(); });

    return additionWindow;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = createMainWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createMainWindow();
    }
});

// ---

electronIpcMain.on('open-addition-window', () => {
    additionWindow = createAdditionWindow();
})

electronIpcMain.on('update-numbers', (event, data) => {
    number1 = data.number1;
    number2 = data.number2;
})
```

---

`preload.js` (main process)

The `preload.js` script containing the IPC methods necessary for communication between the main process and render processes.

```js
// Import the necessary Electron modules
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// Exposed protected methods in the render process
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods
    'ipcRenderer', {
        // From render to main
        openAdditionWindow: () => {
            ipcRenderer.send('open-addition-window');
        },
        updateNumbers: (data) => {
            ipcRenderer.send('update-numbers', data);
        },
        // From main to render
        previousNumbers: (listener) => {
            ipcRenderer.on('previous-numbers', listener)
        }
    }
);
```

---

`main-window.html` (render process)

A basic window containing a button to open the `addition` window via IPC.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Main Window</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Main Window</h1>
        <hr>
        <input type="button" id="openAdditionWindow" value="Open Addition Window">
    </body>

    <script>
        // On button click, open the addition window
        document.getElementById('openAdditionWindow').addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.ipcRenderer.openAdditionWindow();
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

---

`addition-window.html` (render process)

When the window is created, if there are any persistent numbers in the main process, it will send them via IPC. Once received, the local variables will be updated, followed by updating the numbers in the UI.

When the `Generate Numbers` button is clicked, two numbers are randomly generated, updated in the UI and then sent via IPC to the main process for persistence.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Addition Window</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Addition Window</h1>
        <hr>
        <input type="button" id="generateNumbers" value="Generate Numbers">
        <hr>
        <div>
            <span id="number1"></span>
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
            <span id="number2"></span>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script>
        let number1;
        let number2;

        let numberOneSpan = document.getElementById('number1');
        let numberTwoSpan = document.getElementById('number2');

        // Listen for IPC message from main process to render process
        window.ipcRenderer.previousNumbers((event, data) => {
            number1 = data.number1;
            number2 = data.number2;
            updateNumbers(number1, number2);
        });

        // Listen for click on Generate Numbers button
        document.getElementById('generateNumbers').addEventListener('click', () => {
            number1 = generateNumber();
            number2 = generateNumber();

            updateNumbers(number1, number2);

            window.ipcRenderer.updateNumbers({'number1': number1, 'number2': number2});
        })

        // Generate a random number
        function generateNumber() {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        }

        // Update numbers in UI
        function updateNumbers(number1, number2) {
            numberOneSpan.innerText = number1;
            numberTwoSpan.innerText = number2;
        }
    </script>
</html>
```